# Using relative adverbs ("whom", "who" and "which")

Tags: relative-adverbs

Could I use both variants of the sentences?

1. Whom / Who are you waiting for?
2. Which of the girls is Ann?

Comment: "Whom", "who" and "which" are relative pronouns not adverbs. And in your examples they are interrogative pronouns. But the answer is yes your questions are correct although I'd prefer "Which girl is Ann?"

Comment: "Who" is preferred in (1) because the relative pronoun doesn't follow the preposition; plus, no one uses "whom" anymore. @Laure I don't see why you'd favor that version over the one being discussed.

Comment: @userr2684291 Preferences are personal matters and do not always to be justified ! If you wanted to know if there was a grammatical reason, the answer is no.

Comment: Hey, I use whom occasionally

Comment: @userr2684291 It's utterly incorrect to say that no one uses "whom" any more. People use it all of the time.

Comment: @userr2684291 I use "whom" several times a day and so do many of the people to whom I speak.

Comment: So as far as I understood I could use both of them (who, whom) the only one aspect is using it with preposition (like in this case "for")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Americans disdain "whom" and rarely if ever use it.  Instead we would just say "who":

> Who are you waiting for?
>
> Who gave you the answer?
>
> Who did you give the answer to?

You will find "whom" in British English, so it depends on who you are talking to (or *to whom* you are talking).  If you must use it, [here is some guidance](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/who-vs-whom-its-not-as-complicated-as-you-might-think/)

> - Who should be used to refer to the subject of a sentence.
> - Whom should be used to refer to the object of a verb or preposition.

So in this case you should use

> Whom are you waiting for?

but as this sounds inelegant, since it's a sentence that ends with a preposition,   I think most would prefer:

> For whom are you waiting?

I'm not sure of your question with "Which of the girls is Ann?" but it's perfectly grammatical.  Of course, you can say it more simply as:

> Which girl is Ann?

or even

> Which is Ann?

Side note:  There is argument about whether it is "proper" to end a sentence with a preposition.  As you can see in this answer, I do, but if you are interested in the debate you may watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OLxLK_R6jQ).

Comment: Good explanation and references